# Vico charts android rounding to the nearest 10

Tags: android, kotlin, graph, charts, android-jetpack-compose

I am using vico charts library for android jetpack compose. And I want to round values of startAxis to the nearest 10 and change point. For example, I want to make values of vertical axis to be (11,21,32...) instead of (10,20,30...) like in the images.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12e1P.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esn7q.png)

I tried using AxisValueFormatter, but it only changes the label, not the position of the axis point itself

Answer (score 1):

In order to customize the values of the start axis where ticks, labels, and gridlines are displayed, create an implementation of AxisItemPlacer.Vertical and override "getLabelValues" to return your preferred values. This behavior is referred to on the [vico Axes wiki](https://patrykandpatrick.com/vico/wiki/axes).

```
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.core.axis.AxisItemPlacer
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.core.axis.AxisPosition
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.core.axis.vertical.VerticalAxis
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.core.chart.draw.ChartDrawContext

class MyVerticalAxisItemPlacer : AxisItemPlacer.Vertical {
    // Do ticks for 0, 10.5, 21, 31.5, etc.
    // Assuming you round the display values, these will show as 0,11,21,32,42,53...
    override fun getLabelValues(
        context: ChartDrawContext,
        axisHeight: Float,
        maxLabelHeight: Float,
        position: AxisPosition.Vertical
    ): List<Float> {
        val labelList = mutableListOf<Float>()
        // Use a maxValue relative to the maximum in your data set - axisHeight is in pixels and so is NOT useful relative to the tick values
        for (i in 0..maxValue) {
            labelList.add((i * 10.5F).toFloat())
        }
        return labelList.toList()
    }

    // Return the default implementation for the other required functions
    override fun getBottomVerticalAxisInset(
        verticalLabelPosition: VerticalAxis.VerticalLabelPosition,
        maxLabelHeight: Float,
        maxLineThickness: Float
    ): Float {
        return AxisItemPlacer.Vertical.default().getBottomVerticalAxisInset(
            verticalLabelPosition,
            maxLabelHeight,
            maxLineThickness
        )
    }
    ...
}
```

Then, pass an instance of this custom class as the itemPlacer on your Chart's startAxis:

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.compose.axis.vertical.rememberStartAxis
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.compose.chart.Chart


// Use remember so a new instance is not created each time the view recomposes
val verticalItemPlacer by remember { mutableStateOf(MyVerticalAxisItemPlacer()) }
Chart(
    ...
    startAxis = rememberStartAxis(
            itemPlacer = verticalItemPlacer
        ),
    ...
)
```